# I have a ajax compatibility question when reading from an XML file works in Safari only

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

Ok I am testing this in 3 different browsers...

The lastest Safari, the latest FireFox and the latest Google Chrome...

Problem is this script only works for Safari...anyone know why?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // Interpret response
        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {

            // Example: Show the XML tag in the console
            console.log(this);

            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("hnn"));

        });
    }
});
```

The output works perfectly for safari yet it won't output anything in the other browsers.

```
<div id="divOutput"></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're running on `nfl.com`, you can't make AJAX requests cross-site.

You might want to try this [RSS reading jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed), though.